# Using Zend_PDF and Zend Framework, Loading Libraries in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I’m new to PHP, only having worked with a LAMP stack a little bit. I would like to use Zend_PDF to fill forms using PHP. I am having issues and believe I do not know how to properly load Zend Framework (or external libraries in general). Here is what I have currently:

```
<?php 
include_path='.:/var/www/html/lib/'; 
require_once'.:/var/www/html/lib/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php';
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('.:/var/www/html/forms/test.pdf');

echo count($pdf->pages);
?>
```

I was using `count();` as a test but I’m looking to use the `setTextField();` functions. I do not have a “/Loader/Autoloader.php” as referenced in some guides.

How do I properly load the library so that I can use the `setTextField();` function?

PHP 5.4.16,
Zend Framework 2.4.4,
CentOS7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your question.

Firstly, the `Zend_Pdf` you mentioned above belongs to ZF1, not ZF2. If you really are talking about ZF2, then the class is called `ZendPdf` and can be used as a standalone component - you do not need to have a full copy of ZF2 available for the autloading (composer will generate an autoloader - you will just need to `require` that in your script). Last time I checked (which, admittedly, was a couple of years ago), the two versions were functionally equivalent, so you should probably just use the version that matches the version of Zend Framework that you're actually using.

Which brings me to the next issue. Because I wasn't completely sure which version you were referring to, I did a quick text search and discovered that the `setTextField()` method only exists in `Zend_Pdf` from ZF1, not the `ZendPdf` class that is related to ZF2, so I'm not sure why you mentioned ZF2 in your question. But anyway, I figured out how to get the ZF2 version working before I made that discovery, so I've included both methods below for completeness.

Also, you have an error in your `require_once` statement - it should not have the '.:' included at the start. Now on to my actual answer.

**Loading `Zend_Pdf` from Zend Framework 1 Standalone**

This should work:

```
set_include_path( '/path/to/zf1/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once( '/path/to/zf1/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' );
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

$pdf->pages[0] = new Zend_Pdf_Page( Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4 );
$pdf->pages[0]->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 24 );

$pdf->pages[0]->drawText( "Hello world!", 240, 400 );

$pdf->save( 'example.pdf' );
```

You will obviously need to adjust the paths in the code above in order to make it work properly, but once you do that and run the script, you should end up with example.pdf being created.

**Loading `ZendPdf` from Zend Framework 2 Standalone**

Download the `ZendPdf` project from github (https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf) using the instructions on the project page or clone the repository directly using `git` if you prefer.

Change into the directory where `ZendPdf` has been placed and run `composer install` to download the supporting files.

In that same directory (ie. the project root of `ZendPdf`), create a file called `test.php` with the following contents:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use ZendPdf\PdfDocument;
use ZendPdf\Page;
use ZendPdf\Font;

$pdf = new PdfDocument();

$pdf->pages[0] = new Page( Page::SIZE_A4 );
$pdf->pages[0]->setFont( Font::fontWithName( Font::FONT_HELVETICA ), 24 );
$pdf->pages[0]->drawText( 'Hello world!', 240, 400 );

$pdf->save( 'example.pdf' );
```

Run `php test.php` and the example.pdf file should be created.

The magic in that second solution comes from `composer`, which creates the `autoload.php` file for you. There are many, many benefits to using this approach, one of which is that you don't have to have a full copy of Zend Framework 2 installed simply to get a working autoloader.

Comment: What an amazing answer, thank you so much. I was referring to ZF2 but did not realize Zend_Pdf was only in ZF1. After testing it out it looks like ZendPdf doesn’t have the ability to edit text fields, only draw. I suppose I’ll be playing with coordinates for a while. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome - glad I could help. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: I do have one more question, if you could still help me. '$filename = 'new.pdf';
$pdf->save( $filename );' works while '$filename = '/forms/new.pdf';
$pdf->save( $filename );' doesn't. how do I save/open in other directories?

Comment: What happens when you try to save to the /forms directory? Do you get a message saying "Can not open '/forms/new.pdf' for writing"? If so, it is most likely a problem with file permissions. You need to ensure that the directory you are trying to save the file to (A) exists and (B) is writable by the user (or group) that the script is running as.

Comment: Looks like that was it, along with changing it to 'forms/new.pdf'. Thanks!